# HandleChallengeAsync return custom object

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core

I am implementing my [AuthenticationHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-3.0). I have overridden the method

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

with my custom logic of authentification. Now I am trying to return custom object if the authentification is failed. For that I am overriding a `HandleChallengeAsync` method

```
protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    await base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);

    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult(ErrorResponseDTO.CreateInvalidApiKey());

    string output = "authentification is failed"// result.ToJsonString(); // how to serialize?

    await Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output));
}
```

This method returns the *"authentification is failed"* string in the response body.
I would like to return a custom object serialized to json in the response body . But I don't understand how correctly to serialize my object to json string according json formatter setting specified in Startup file?

There is a following setting in my Startup file.

```
services
    .AddMvc(option =>
    {
        option.EnableEndpointRouting = true;
        option.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new DateTimeModelBinderProvider());
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new NullableDateTimeConverter());
    });
```

Sure I can just write directly JSON.Net serialization like below

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ErrorResponseDTO.CreateInvalidApiKey());
```

But I would like to use already tuned json formatter. Could I get access to json formatter? Or maybe there is a easy way to convert JsonResult to json string according the json formatter?

Answer (score 2):

I came across [an article](https://kristian.hellang.com/using-mvc-result-executors-in-middleware/) and it helped me a lot.

There is an [`IActionResultExecutor<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactionresultexecutor-1?view=aspnetcore-3.0) interface

> which can execute a particular kind of IActionResult by manipulating
>   the HttpResponse.

The interface is registered in the DI container, so I can have an access to it and execute `IActionResult` by it. So my task has been simplified and I need only:

1. create [`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) object instance. I am creating [`ObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) object.
2. create [`ActionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext?view=aspnetcore-3.0) object instance
3. execute `IActionResult` by `IActionResultExecutor<TResult>`

I have written the extension method which implements above steps. It looks like

```
public static class HttpResponseExtension
{
    private static readonly RouteData EmptyRouteData = new RouteData();

    private static readonly ActionDescriptor EmptyActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();

    public static Task WriteModelAsync<TModel>(this HttpContext context, TModel model)
    {
        var result = new ObjectResult(model)
        {
            DeclaredType = typeof(TModel)
        };

        var executor = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>>();

        var routeData = context.GetRouteData() ?? EmptyRouteData;
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, EmptyActionDescriptor);
        return executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
    }
}
```

After that the `HandleChallengeAsync` method looks very simple.

```
protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    await base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);

    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    var errorObj = ErrorResponseDTO.CreateInvalidApiKey();

    await Context.WriteModelAsync(errorObj);
}
```

Thus, the method returns a custom object written to the response body in the global format specified for actions of controllers in the `StartUp` class. So, if the formatting setting will be changed in the `StartUp` class , the changes will be applied for authentification layer as well.